# If $x^{x^4} = 4$, what is the value of $x^{x^2} + x^{x^8}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

If $x^{x^4} = 4$, what is the value of $x^{x^2} + x^{x^8}$ ?

I can find by trial and error, that $x=\sqrt 2$. But, what is the general process to answer questions like this?

Comment: This is a problem from a regional mathematical olympiad.

Comment: Thank you for being honest about that.  Could you provide a reference?  Is the contest still going on?  There is a [policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy) about ongoing contest problems, but if the contest has already concluded then there is no problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz no it is an old problem which can be found [here] (http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/subjects/mathematics/previous-question-papers-and-solutions/new-prermo2014.pdf).

Comment: How about this two-step approach. you first find a simpler equation for some sub-expression, solve it and then use it to deduce the final value.
$$x^{x^4} = 4 \implies \left(x^4\right)^{x^4} = x^{4x^4} = \left(x^{x^4}\right)^4 = 4^4 \implies x^4 = 4 \implies x = \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: @achillehui You should make that an answer. And I could've sworn I saw this question here before (can't find it now).

Comment: @achillehui I'm a bit hesitant at your second $\Rightarrow$.  Is it true that if $a^a = b^b$ that $a=b$?  Assuming that $a^a\neq 1$ at least to avoid the whole $0^0=1^1$ bit.

Comment: @JMoravitz $x^x$ is a monotonic increasing function for $x \ge 1$ and $\le 1$ for $x \in (0,1]$. As long as we are dealing with +ve $x$, we are safe.

Comment: @mickep indeed it is so, should I mark this as duplicate seeing that JMoravitz has written an answer?

Comment: I think you can do that anyways, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the logarithm base 2 of each side, we have

$\log_2 (x^{x^4}) = x^4\log_2 (x)= \log_2 4 = 2$

Multiplying each side by four we have

$4x^4\log_2 (x) = x^4\log_2 (x^4) = 8$

Relabeling $x^4$ as $u$, we have

$u\log_2(u) = 8$

Utilizing the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we have that

$u = e^{W(8\ln 2)}=e^{W(4\ln 4)}=4$

Replacing back, $x^4=4$ and the result follows.

---

For the conclusion to the problem, we found earlier that $x^4=4$ and so either $x^2=2$ or $x^2=-2$.  Assuming that we require $x$ to be real, it must be the first.

$\begin{array}{rl}
x^{x^2} + x^{x^8} &=x^2 + x^{(x^4)^2}\\
&=2+x^{16}\\
&=2+(x^4)^4\\
&=2+4^4\\
&=2+256\\
&=258\end{array}$

Comment: $W(8 ln 2)= ln 4$?

Comment: @RishavKundu as it so happens, yes.  Added one more step that should clear it up above.  [wolfram-link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e^%28LambertW%28ln+2^8%29%29)

Comment: Ok I found the relevant identity on wikipedia, thanks.